# Break out of a python for loop using boolean flag, logic and indentation error

Tags: python, list, loops, boolean, break

I have the following code that seeks to search the list of usernames, and simply return the output "Found in index i" or "Sorry username not found", on first output.

```
usernames=["u1","u2","u3"]
found=False

while found==False:
  username=input("Enter username:")
  for i in range(len(usernames)):
    if username==usernames[i]:
      found=True
      break

if found==True:
  print("Username found in index:",i)
else:
  print("Sorry,username not found")
```

The current code seems to work if the username is right but if erroneous data is used e.g 23234, then it repeats the question and does not jump to the if statement at the bottom of the code (that's what I want).

Could someone please correct this code with an explanation on the most efficient way to solve this problem. It is likely something to do with the boolean flag 'found', and I do not understand why it is not breaking out and going to the bottom if statement. Thanks in advance

Comment: put an else block to handle the error data

Comment: "Indentation error"?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about breaking out of nested loops, but consider an easier way to determine if a string is in a list: `if username in usernames:`

Comment: remove the outer while loop...?

Comment: You don't need the while loop at all, just set found to true if there's a match and thats it.

Comment: Kevin and RnD -yes that would be easy and I'm aware of the username in usernames option, but for teaching purposes we need this particular algorithm!

Comment: @MissComputing I posted an answer using your current approach, see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the `while` block?

```
usernames=["u1","u2","u3"]
index = 0
found = False

username = input("Enter username:")
for i in range(len(usernames)):
  if username == usernames[i]:
    found = True
    index = i
    break

if found:
  print("Username found in index:",index)
else:
  print("Sorry,username not found")
```

Comment: That doesn't work. NameError: name 'found' is not defined

Comment: `for index, candidate in enumerate(usernames): if username == candidate:...` would be more idiomatic than iterating over a range.

Comment: `if found:`, not `if found == True:`.

Comment: Yes, works! but it makes me wonder if the most efficient way is without a flag at all. Can it be done without the found=false and just the if statement inside a for loop!?

Comment: @MissComputing yes, it can. but efficiency will be almost the same.

Comment: can you post that please - I'm after, as mentioned, the most efficient, simplest way to do it using a for loop (not using any string manipulation). So just selection and iteration if possible.

Comment: This produces three "not founds" https://repl.it/@teachyourselfpython/search-list-of-usernames-for-username-using-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

You do not need those boolean flags, range based loops or extra if conditions:

```
usernames=["u1","u2","u3"]

while True:
  user = input("Enter username: ")    
  if user in usernames:
    print("Username found at Index: {}".format(usernames.index(user)))
    break
  else:
    print("Sorry, username not found. Try again")
```

**EDIT**:

But if you must continue with your current approach of using for-loop, put an else block on the outer for loop and break if found:

```
usernames = ["u1","u2","u3"]
found = False

while found == False:
  username = input("Enter username: ")
  for i in range(len(usernames)):
    if username == usernames[i]:
        print("Username found at Index: {}".format(i))
        break
  else: # not and indentation error
        print("Sorry, username not found. Try again")
```

**EDIT 2**: (without boolean flags)

```
usernames = ["u1","u2","u3"]

while True:
  username = input("Enter username: ")
  for i in range(len(usernames)):
    if username == usernames[i]:
        print("Username found at Index: {}".format(i))
        break
  else: # not and indentation error
        print("Sorry, username not found. Try again")
```

**OUTPUT** (in all cases):

```
Enter username: 2334
Sorry, username not found. Try again
Enter username: u2
Username found at Index: 1
```

Comment: I'm stumped! - Thank you - this works, but I do not understand it all. How come the 'else' is on the indentation level of the 'for' and not the original 'if'. I clearly don't understand python indentation. I had tried the exact same thing so was logically correct, but my else was on the same line was the 'if' and it repeated blocks

Comment: MIles Davis - can you explain? When I change the if and else to be aligned with each other, it doesn't work, but your version with the indentation error?! works//

Comment: @MilesDavis No that's not an error. Python has for/else constructs. Read about it here http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Comment: @MissComputing Think of it like this, if the `else` block is on the `if` level, it would be true if the username is not placed on the first index. for loops also have an else clause!

Comment: My bad, never used for/else statement.

Comment: Excellent - did not know that! Unique to python I assume...!

Comment: Thanks - upvoted. I'm looking however, for the simplest way to solve it using for loops and if. solution 1 doesn't quite work - but ideally something as simple as that would be perfect. https://repl.it/@teachyourselfpython/search-list-of-usernames-for-username-using-for-loop

Comment: @MissComputing Consider the first solution in the answer?

Comment: Simplest would mean elimating the boolean flag if possible. In a language like VB.Net the logic is so obvious so something like this is straightforward with a for loop and nested if. that's it. Why is it different!?!?

Comment: @MissComputing see the edit 2: without the boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

`while found==False:` makes it loop until `found` becomes `True`.
So if it doesn't find the username you are looking for, it loops around and asks you again.

Also, if you want to see if a string exists in a list, just use `list.index()` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
username=input("Enter username:")
try:
    i = usernames.index(username)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry,username not found")
else:
    print("Username found in index:",i)
```

Comment: Yes, and it become 'true' - on the code above, when the username is found. (that bit works). What doesn't work, is that in the other case (when it is not found), I want it to jump to the code below (if statement)and say "Sorry, username not found in list"

Comment: Like I said, the `while found==False:` statement makes it loop like that. If you don't want it to loop, just get rid of this while cycle!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will simply never reach the second if because it is designed to only reach the second `if` if a correct username is entered.

You have to decide to either keep asking for a username until a correct one is entered (that's what you are doing in the `while found == true` bit).

Or you ask only once and see if it is found, for that you need to remove the `while found == true` part.

I see that what you meant was probably what DirtyBit did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183057

Comment: Thank you  - not sure if it answers the question though. Can you correct the code and post a solution such that it does what the question asks i.e "If the username is present, it prints "present in index.." and if not "sorry no username". I do not wish to use "if username in usernames" as we need to use a for loop to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

A better version is this one

```
usernames = ["u1", "u2", "u3"]

while True:
    username = input("Enter username:")

    if username in usernames:
        print("Username found in index:", usernames.index(username))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry,username not found")
```

Edit on request:

```
usernames = ["u1", "u2", "u3"]
found = False

while found is False:
    found = False
    username = input("Enter username:")

    for i in range(len(usernames)):
        if usernames[i] == username:
            print("Username found in index:", i)
            found = True
            break

    if found is False:
        print("Sorry,username not found")
```

Comment: Yes, this is good - but as mentioned I want to use the for loop. I want to solve the problem using a for loop please. (this is for teaching algorithmic purposes)

Comment: It does not work - it repeats the "username found or sorry username" unnecessarily

Comment: @MissComputing Sorry, wrong copy - paste. Try it now